# modal with blurred background with css like in example

Tags: css, user-interface

aye folks!

i spent the last hour searching around the web trying to find a css solution to create something like this [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/3463152-Daily-UI-Challenge-016-Popup)..
i read a lot of 'frosted glass' tutorials.. but like 90% are using two images or blur the whole body of the site while the modal is open.

maybe i just haven't found the right article or it's not possible with css this easily atm. but stack overflow never disappointed me so far. therefore i'm asking you guys if someone does know a solution.

Comment: If you want to only blur the modal, you have to put the same image in the modal, position it so it aligns with the one behind, and blur with css filters. It only uses one image, but you put it in two different elements, I don't know if you already found a solution like that

Comment: Hi Andreas. You will need to provide us more work of yours via Code snippet or JsFiddle in order for us to help you :) Cheers

Comment: @LouisLecocq i recreated the example in html/css real quick. not blur tho. thats the point where my struggle begins.
> http://pro.unseen.ninja/andi/flex-modal/

Comment: @mikepa88 i'll have a look into that but i tried something similar with the effect that the image isn't lined up perfectly on some resolutions/devices.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sE4Fv/
It is not loading two images. It is using the same. Setting it both with background-attachment fixed and background-size cover. (like parallax effect finally https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm)

I see this possibility. :/ Quite like mikepa88 said earlier.

Comment: @LouisLecocq yeah.. i guess thats one solution but it does blur an image.. not the website itself. the best possible outcome would be a way to blur everything thats displayed behind the modal.

Comment: @AndreasGrafen yeah, that is not possible.

Comment: @mikepa88 aye. at least i know that for sure now. i'll have a look if i find a workaround with js.. i guess thats would be possible somehow.
but thats for your time and answers! (: